# Disable middle click on Elan touchpad and xinput on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: touchpad, lenovo

Very happy with GNOME (on X, no wayland) and Ubuntu 17.10 except for middle click set up by default on my touchpad. I hit it by mistake all the time and middle click seems to be mapped to "do some crazy stuff" in every app. I really need to disable it.

I'm on a 2017 Lenovo Yoga with a Elan touchpad. I am using libinput and don't have the synaptics driver installed. All the solutions I found reference synaptics. I tried going that route but it made the touchpad much worse, so I'd like to avoid that.

Answer (score 3):

Of course I figure it out right after posting :) Putting the answer here just in case anyone else sees this

Find your touchpad ID:

```
adam@adam720:~$ xinput list | grep -i elan
⎜   ↳ ELAN0651:00 04F3:3052 Touchpad            id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

Find the ID of the middle click property:

```
adam@adam720:~$ xinput --list-props 14 | grep  -i middle
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (320):    1
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (321):    0
```

Toggle the middle click property. In my case it was set to 0, so I set it to 1:

```
adam@adam720:~$ xinput --set-prop 14 320 1
```

In the example above 14 is the ID of the touchpad and 320 is the ID of the property.

Now, this worked, but it also raises some questions that I can't answer.

1. Why was Middle Click Enabled set to 0 by default, and why did 1 turn it off?
2. What is "Middle Click Enabled Default" and why does it error out if you try to set it?

**EDIT!**
I wanted to make this persistent across reboots but I ran into a problem. The device and prop IDs change on boot. So, I wrote a script that looks for the device and prop IDs and then sets the middle button prop to off accordingly. I doubt anyone else will ever need it, but just in case I put the script on [github](https://github.com/adamrdrew/disable-middle-click)

Answer (score 1):

You can edit touchpad config in xorg.conf.d

```
Option "MiddleEmulation" "1"
```

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/disco/en/man4/libinput.4.html

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Adam's solution, the following single line identifies the id of the TouchPad (assuming it is Synaptics TouchPad) and DISABLES the middle-click as well (by setting it to 1):

```
xinput set-prop `xinput list | grep 'Synaptics TouchPad' | grep -oP '(?<=id=)[0-9]+'` "libinput Middle Emulation Enabled" 1
```

Enjoy!